# How do I use Listener to pass a string to another class

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton, setter

Am am writing a simple browser, which has two classes, SimpleBrowser and MyTabbedPane.
 SimpleBrowser has some Gui components such as JButton and TextField, while MyTabbedPane has tabbedpane which has JEditorPane.
I want to pass the Search string entered in SimpleBrowser JTextField into JEditorPane which is in MyTabbedPane
i don't how to use getter and setter
Here some of my code

```
 package com.mysimplebrowser;  

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;  
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;  
import javax.swing.*;  

 class SimpleBrowser extends JFrame{  
    private JTextField myField;  
    private JButton myButton;    
    private JPanel myPanel;  
    private MyTabbedPane myTabbedPane;  

    public SimpleBrowser(){  
        setSize(400, 400);  

        myPanel = new JPanel(); // panel  
        myField = new JTextField();  
        myPanel.add(myField);  

        myButton = new JButton("Search");  
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
                // how do i go about here  
              }  
        });  
        myPanel.add(myButton);  
        // i have left out some code  

        add(myPanel);  
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    }  

    class MyTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane{  
        private String searchWord;  
        private JEditorPane myEditorPane;  

        public MyTabbedPane(){  
            // i have left some code out  
            myEditorPane = new JEditorPane();  
            // i have left out some code for the HTML kit  

            // i want later to add google Ajax api code or the depreciated  
            // google SOAP jar apis but am stuck on how to pass the String  
            // entered in the class SimpleBrowser JTextField into  
            // MyTabbedPane private String SearchWord  

            String myUrl = "http://localhost/Good" + searchWord + "html";  
            myEditorPane.setPage(myUrl); // left out some try ... catch code  
        }  
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args){  
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {  
            public void run() {  
                new SimpleBrowser().setVisible(true);  
            }  
        });  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct -- use getters and setters and you are also correct that you don't want SimpleBrowser's button's ActionListener creating a new MyTabbedPane object inside its actionPerformed since your program should only have one MyTabbedPane object. In my example below I called the "setter" method `sendUrlText(...)` since that's what it does (in my mind anyway). Passing information between classes is no different for Swing code as it is for non-GUI code:

```
class SimpleBrowser extends JFrame {
   private JTextField myField;
   private JButton myButton;
   private JPanel myPanel;
   private MyTabbedPane myTabbedPane = new MyTabbedPane(this);

   public SimpleBrowser() {
      setSize(400, 400); // should be setting preferredSize!

      myPanel = new JPanel(); // panel
      myField = new JTextField();
      myPanel.add(myField);

      myButton = new JButton("Search");
      myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String urlText = myField.getText();
            myTabbedPane.sendUrlText(urlText);
         }
      });
      myPanel.add(myButton);
      // i have left out some code

      add(myPanel);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   }

   class MyTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {
      private String searchWord;
      private JEditorPane myEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
      private SimpleBrowser simpleBrowser; // you'll need this later, 
      // if  you separate these two classes -- which you should do.

      public MyTabbedPane(SimpleBrowser simpleBrowser) {
         this.simpleBrowser = simpleBrowser; 
      }

      public void sendUrlText(String urlText) {
         // TODO set editor pane's page here using urlText
         try {
            myEditorPane.setPage(urlText);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }

      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleBrowserTest mainPanel = new SimpleBrowserTest();

      JFrame frame = new SimpleBrowser();
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: +1, that's what I think is the right approach, taking everything outside the constructor. Just that seeker failed to mention, where exactly he is making an object of `MyTabbedPane` class that led to confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Make two method inside your `SimpleBrowser`class like

```
String searchText = new String();

public void setSearchText(String text)
{
    searchText = text;
}

public String getSearchText()
{
    return searchText;
}
```

And call this method from the `actionPerformed(...)`, inside `SimpleBrowser` class, before making an object of `MyTabbedPane` class, like `setSearchText(myField.getText())`. And inside the constructor of the `MyTabbedPane`, the first line would be `searchWord = getSearchText();`

Comment: The `actionPerformed()` body should look like this: `myTabbedPane.setSearchText(myField.getText());`

Comment: But point comes, he is writing everything in the constructor of the MyTabbedPane() class, so if he makes a new Object and then call this method, till that time that thing is done. Either he has to move everything to outside his constructor, so I just made a few changes.